# Find intersection between two custom UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview

Is there any method in iPhone to find the intersection of two custom UIView (lets say two views are circular and are in same super view).
If there is no such method, what is the best way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`s are all of rectangular shape.

If you need custom shapes, you need to check for yourself. With circular shapes, this is not complicated (take distance of centers and the radius of each one).

Answer (score 5):

You could use [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect).

**CGRectIntersectsRect**
Returns whether two rectangles intersect.

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect (
   CGRect rect1,
   CGRect rect2
);
```

**Parameters**
**rect1**
The first rectangle to examine.
**rect2**
The second rectangle to examine.

There's an example on this question [Objective-C: Issue with CGRect .frame intersect/contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876763/objective-c-problem-with-cgrect-frame-intersect-contains)